# stackexchange redis hashscan return all fields in one time

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using stackexchange.redis SDK in C#, and wish to scan my hash set.
I expected the SDK executed as redis client(when I execute "hscan myKey 0", it will return several key-value pairs, and an cursor which I'll use for the next scan). But when I use stackexchange.redis SDK to implement the "hashscan" method as following:

```
redisCache.HashScan(myKey, pageSize:10, cursor: 0)
```

It will return all the fields in "myKey", there are 2,000 key-value pairs in it.
How can I let it just return several results at one time?

Cause In the future, there will be millions of fields in "myKey", if they all return at one time, it'll cost lots of memory, and will it block the online service? Cause redis is single thread application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It isn't doing quite what you think it is doing. The `HashScan` method here returns a custom iterator which maintains at most 2 pages of data; when you get near the end of one page, it fetches the next page automatically. Essentially, then, if you only want to read 20 items, **just read 20 items**. For example, LINQs `.Take(20)` would work fine. If you call `.ToList()` on the iterator, then yes: it will walk from one end to the other, fetching data dynamically as it needs. So: *don't do that* :)

Things it **does not** do:

- fetch all the data in a single huge call to redis
- perform lots of small calls to redis **before** returning from the `HashScan` method

As a side note: the custom iterator implements a custom interface to allow you to pick up and resume cursors, *if you need that*.

Answer (score 0):

`HashScan` only works if key is matched but not pattern also below solution does not work in production because of huge number of keys.

```
return server.Keys(pattern: key + "*").Select(key => (string)key)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).